# How does the pion decay constant $f_{\pi}$ depend on the number of flavors $N_f$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, pions

I know that for standard QCD with quarks, chiral symmetry breaking occurs for around 4 - 5 light/active quarks - i.e. pions, or generally pseudoscalar goldstone bosons, definitely appear in the spectrum for $N_f=1,2,3,4$.

My question is, within $N_f=1,\ldots, 4$, how does the pion decay constant vary with respect to $N_f$? I can't seem to find that answer in the literature.

Comment: How is it possible to have a pion with $N_f=1$ in the first place?

Comment: @probably_someone I don't know... But I feel like I've seen people talking about pions even with $N_f=1$, though yeah it doesn't really make sense to me.